# WooCommerce Email Template Formatting Incorrectly

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to use a custom customer-on-hold-order.php template for woocommerce emails. I have the custom file place here /wp-content/betheme-child/woocommerce/emails/customer-on-hold-order.php

The custom template is working so it's in the correct place. I am receiving this template in my email. However the formatting is screwed up.

[image: messed up formatting]

I ONLY changed the text above the order summary (I know there is a typo). Deleted one sentence and replaced with a new sentence. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I even tried overwriting the file in the woocommerce plugin folder, but had the same result. I tried clearing Woocommerce template cache and wordpress cache, but no joy.

For reference here is the original template:

[image: original template]

Comment: can we see your code please/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you copied the plain text template to make your custom template and placed it in the HTML version custom place.

To overwrite the template correctly, you need to overwrite.

the HTML version from

```
`woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-on-hold-order.php`
```

to

```
`betheme-child/woocommerce/emails/customer-on-hold-order.php`
```

and overwrite the plain text version from

```
woocommerce/templates/emails/plain/customer-on-hold-order.php
```

to

```
betheme-child/woocommerce/emails/plain/customer-on-hold-order.php
```

Comment: I did not have both versions of the email copied in to the theme folder. I did that, but still same result.

Here is a link to the full code:

https://gist.github.com/mverminski/d2b343790be2d66a9f63f381d294cacb

Comment: Double check that plain version is placed in plain folder. If that's right, then check the "Email Type" field  in WooCommerce->settings->Emails->Order on-hold. It should be HTML

Comment: I can verify it is placed in child-theme/woocommerce/emails/plain and the email settings are set to HTML